# Embeddable Common Lisp (ECL) with D Programming Language?

Tags: common-lisp, d, ecl

Is there a way to use the Embeddable Common Lisp with the D Programming Language?
Something like a Derelict library?

Comment: The way I'd do it is to find some C examples and write the necessary struct and function definitions over in D, using `extern(C)` then link it in with plain `-L-lecl` (or however you'd do it in C too). But I haven't used ecl myself so I don't have more than that as an answer.